# splitting separate bashrcs for different purposes

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I was wondering if I can split my .bashrc into separate parts, and linux will pick up both files and use them correctly. I have general purpose scripts like 'cleanproject', and scripts that are only for certain tasks at work like 'checkin'. I want to automate updating my permanent .bashrc in my Bitbucket, but I don't wanna grab useless stuff I use at work that will pollute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can!  Just call one script from another using the `source` command.  For example, your .bashrc might be:

**`.bashrc`**

```
#!/bin/bash
source cleanproject.sh
source checkin.sh
```

**`cleanproject.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash
alias mousepos='$TBRANCH/mousepos.py'
alias xdo='/tmp/xdotool_script.txt'
```

**`checkin.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash
cloner() { $PYCOMPLETE/git_cloner.py "$@" ;}
```

Comment: and those things I called are the normal bashrc stuff like alias mousepos='$TBRANCH/mousepos.py'

alias xdo='/tmp/xdotool_script.txt'

cloner() { $PYCOMPLETE/git_cloner.py "$@" ;}

Comment: @codyc4321 See edited answer.  I included sample scripts based on your comment.